# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

tengo este recuadro:

```
<div id="context_menu" class="" style="top: 206px; left: 542px; display: block;">
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('eliminar')">Eliminar Fichero seleccionado/s</div> 
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('download_as_zip')">Descargar seleccionado</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('export')">Exportar a Excel</div>
</div>
```

Y quiero que no se vea el div que contiene el "enviar", lo que viene a ser esto en css:

```
div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3){display:none;}
```

he probado hacerlo así (sin éxito):

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)");
/*var y = document.getElementsByTagName("div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)")[0];*/
  y.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

¿Cómo debería de hacerlo (solo usando JS)?

Comment: Cuando usas `.getElementsByTagName()` solo debes especificar la etiqueta y tú estás pasando un selector CSS completo, entonces, deberías usar `.querySelector()`.

Comment: si cierto, eso también lo probé y sigue dando un "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined". Y aunque no me diese ese error no tengo ni idea de donde poner el ":nth-child(3)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la función `querySelector()` que usa selectores **CSS**, por lo que te resultará muy amigable al tener una traslación casi directa de lo que estabas haciendo con **CSS**.

```js
document.querySelector('div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)').style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div id="context_menu" class="" style="top: 206px; left: 542px; display: block;">
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('eliminar')">Eliminar Fichero seleccionado/s</div> 
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('download_as_zip')">Descargar seleccionado</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('export')">Exportar a Excel</div>
</div>
```

**Referencias:** [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Muchas gracias, menudo crack, la verdad es que no conocía el querySelector() hace poco que volví a tocar js después de 5 años sin tocarlo.

Answer (score 2):

**Por que quieres específicamente encontrar los elementos con este tipo de query?** Cuando es algo que necesitas repetir, como aplicar un evento en todos los elementos puedes utilizar algún query de este tipo, pero si quieres aplicar algo en una etiqueta especifica y que conoces, pues solo agrégale un id.

Igualmente aunque recalco lo de arriba, lo que está pasando es muy simple, primero `getElementsByTagName` no admite este tipo de queries y segundo aunque hubiese una o mas etiquetas `getElementsByTagName` devuelve un array con elementos encontrados (**ojo**), **solo para que te des una idea** `var y = document.getElementsByTagName("div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)");` siempre va a ser `undefined` y el error es bastante explicito, undefined no es un objeto y por lo tanto no tiene ninguna propiedad que se llame `setAttribute`.

**En su lugar solo deberías utilizar `querySelector` que esta hecho especificamente para utilizar css queries**:

```js
var y = document.querySelector("div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)");
/*var y = document.getElementsByTagName("div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)")[0];*/
  y.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

```html
<div id="context_menu" class="" style="top: 206px; left: 542px; display: block;">
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('eliminar')">Eliminar Fichero seleccionado/s</div> 
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('download_as_zip')">Descargar seleccionado</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('export')">Exportar a Excel</div>
</div>
```

**Igualmente, no es mas fácil simplemente usar una id en lugar de harcodear queries? jeje**

```js
var y = document.getElementById("enviar");
 y.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
```

```html
<div id="context_menu" class="" style="top: 206px; left: 542px; display: block;">
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('eliminar')">Eliminar Fichero seleccionado/s</div> 
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('download_as_zip')">Descargar seleccionado</div>
    <div id="enviar" class="menu_item" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('export')">Exportar a Excel</div>
</div>
```

Un saludo, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si por algún motivo necesitas hacerlo según la vieja escuela ([querySelector y querySelectosAll no son compatibles con todos los navegadores](https://caniuse.com/queryselector)), sin entrar en discusiones sobre si debes mejorar o no la estructura de tus elementos e implementar mejores prácticas, como evitar el uso de funciones in-line, la forma de hacer lo que pretendes sería seleccionar el `div` padre por su id primero y luego el div hijo por su la clase:

```js
var y=document.getElementById( 'context_menu' ).getElementsByClassName( 'menu_item' )[2];
/*Test*/
console.log(y);
y.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
```

```html
<div id="context_menu" class="" style="top: 206px; left: 542px; display: block;">
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('eliminar')">Eliminar Fichero seleccionado/s</div> 
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('download_as_zip')">Descargar seleccionado</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('export')">Exportar a Excel</div>
</div>
```

Ten en cuenta que `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve un array de elementos con esa clase, y los arrays empiezan desde el índice `0`, como quieres el tercer elemento, por uso pusimos `2` como índice.

Si quieres modernizar tu código, como bien han señalado los compañeros, puedes usar `querySelector`, que te da más posibilidades de seleccionar los elementos: por tipo, por id, por clase, por posición.

```js
document.querySelector('div#context_menu>div:nth-child(3)').style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div id="context_menu" class="" style="top: 206px; left: 542px; display: block;">
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('eliminar')">Eliminar Fichero seleccionado/s</div> 
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('download_as_zip')">Descargar seleccionado</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</div>
    <div class="menu_item" onclick="do_action('export')">Exportar a Excel</div>
</div>
```